# iOS - How to get raw offset for timezone?

Tags: ios, timezone, nstimezone

How do I get the raw offset in milliseconds for Coordinated Universal Time in iOS programmatically?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
NSInteger millisecondsFromGMT = 1000 * [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
```

In Swift 3 and Swift 4:

```
let millisecondsFromGmt = 1000 * TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent.secondsFromGMT()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see answer to my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31988549/3004003

It seems to be more precise regarding expression *raw offset*, because "raw" actually should mean "without DST at all", like it is in Java (`getRawOffset()` in `java.util.TimeZone` class)