# Objective C - How to get raw offset (without DST) using NSTimeZone

Tags: objective-c, dst, nstimezone

I'd like to get raw offset from GMT. I know the answer could be like that:

```
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"];
NSInteger *offset = [zone secondsFromGMT];
```

(like here: [iOS - How to get raw offset for timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188818/ios-how-to-get-raw-offset-for-timezone))

But the problem is, it doesn't give me **raw** offset (for Berlin +1), but only *offset with DST* (+2), that is, for the current date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSTimeZone` has a property `daylightSavingTimeOffset` which returns the difference to the raw offset

```
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"];
NSTimeInterval rawOffset = [zone secondsFromGMT] - [zone daylightSavingTimeOffset];
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be right answer regarding specifically **raw** offset.